# How to handle edits that are too minor, changing title from uppercase to lowercase?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

I've just seen a couple of edit suggestions where a user tried to gain reputation (it otherwise doesn't make any sense to me) with editing the title of a question.

Here a some examples, I did reject, but... there are some more in the reputation history of the user where the edits were accepted.

Some of the ones, I rejected:

- [Android VpnService to <del>capture</del> **Capture** packets](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5762450)
- [Sync <del>data</del> **Data** to server in background like dropbox , evernote does](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5762478)

But also some of the ones I found that got accepted in the reputation history:

- [Rotate and <del>crop</del> **Crop** UIImage](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5762452) (accepted from OP)
- [<del>registerBackButtonAction</del> **RegisterBackButtonAction** working on many views](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5754416)
- [Is it possible to reject the <del>currently</del> **Currently** uploaded binary with "In Review" status?](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5762479) (accepted from OP, but before two times rejected by reviewers)

And now some fun, he did edits the other way round (uppercase to lowercase):

- [Minimal <del>Transversal</del> **transversal** of a Hypergraph](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5762379) (accepted from OP)

Note: This changes were the only one in the edits. I'm not talking about edits where he did a *major* edit for better readbility of the title or addition of missing code indentation e.g.!

I don't want to snitch about that, so I didn't include the name of the user here (but it isn't a big deal to find out about it due to the links).

I just want to know: Am I doing it wrong, rejecting those edits with `invalid edit` or a custom message?
What else should I do, as the `too minor` reason has vanished?

Comment: If it's a specific user obviously abusing things then flag it for a moderator with an appropriate comment. That last one looks fine to me as long as any other obvious issues with the post were properly corrected in the edit too but the others should all be an invalid edit rejection.

Comment: The first three and the fifth are "invalid edit", I don't think they cross the threshold to "vandalism"... The fourth one is "vandalism", as the new capitalization is simply wrong (Though it's a really fine line with all of those). The sixth one is meh, not worth it but someone said we should approve anything if it is the slightest bit of improvement.

Comment: Thanks for these two comments so far. I highly agree to @Deduplicator that the sixth one is a, say, *valid* edit, but I only took this into my list as it was surprisingly the complete opposite of the previous edit intents.

Comment: Just glancing at some other edit approvals, many of those should have been '... and improve' - there are some that are missing things like removing 'enter code here' still in the text.  If I may hazard a guess, the approvals are done by people who have less than a native speaker's command of English.

Comment: IMHO there are few cases where a capital letter makes a very real difference. Most of the time words are perfectly understandable even with typos. [By definition](http://stackoverflow.com/help/editing): *"Edits are expected to be substantial and to leave the post better than you found it."* If you make emphasis in ***substantial*** part and given the fact that those edits led to a very slight improvement, IMO should be totally rejected.

Comment: @dic19 - check this out: [PASSING UNBOUND MULTIDIMENSIONAL ARRAY](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/25830528/revisions). I see two or three a day. The site needs a filter to detect yelling....

Comment: @jww Yeah, indeed, but that referenced edit from you is very good and you really should not compare it with the ones referenced above. Instead this is a nice example how an edit should be, not ending up with just correcting the title uppercase to lowercase, but improving the whole content!

Comment: @jww see also the post on [meta.P.SE](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6850/how-effective-is-the-quality-filter-against-this-question-with-all-caps-brief-ti) about all caps in title (and body).

Comment: Love the way the title of this post about minor edits was edited to add a single comma :)

Comment: @dav_i Oh sh... I don't find any good comment on that. Seems like I just got pwned!

Comment: approve them. you will find that they are approved by robo editors anyways, often your rejection will result in a message that this has already been approved. thats just what you get when offering 2 rep for minor actions: people that will farm them. rejecting those edits will just lead to them being done again and approved by someone else.

Comment: @PaulGregory Then leave perfection for people whose edits don't require approval (or make an exception for the most popular content).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Title edits are generally considered important enough to stand on their own, without being considered too minor. Titles are what draws a reader into the post, so the more attractive and professional looking the title, the better the chances of attracting like-minded professionals who may have answers.

I also approach suggested edits, for the purpose of rep gain, with a healthy dose of skepticism. It's best to approach suggested edit reviews as if the people are legitimately trying to make Stack Overflow better.

But in this case, I agree something is wrong with this picture. Here are two problems I see:

1. The edits to the title changing the lowercase letters to uppercase letters are incorrect. Those words are not proper names, so unless every word in the title is capitalized, only the first word should be capitalized. The first series of edits should be rejected on the basis that they are wrong.
2. The second set of edits, changing an uppercase letter to a lowercase letter, is correct, but the fact that we see the editor arbitrarily making these changes suggests that this person is not acting with the best interests of Stack Overflow in mind.

It may be best to reject edits from this user, until they become more substantial. If possible, try to reject only the edits that are incorrect, but if people are incorrectly rubber stamping these, then we may need to temporarily be a little more liberal in hitting the reject button.

A possible custom message might be something like this:

> Your title edits are inconsistent and incorrect. Please don't edit titles simply to change lowercase to uppercase only on some words. This also needlessly bumps posts.

Comment: Thanks, I second that! So reading this, there comes one question to my mind: Why isn't there an equivalent to the automatic review ban for rejected edits when too many edits are rejected in a specific period?

Comment: Apparently, that's already a thing: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91392/too-many-of-your-edits-were-rejected-try-again-in-7-days, unless I'm misunderstanding your question.

Comment: Ah, I haven't searched the uber-meta for this yet. So 1000 thanks for this reference! Nice to know.

Comment: However "Reading A Post With A Title Which Is All First Letters Capitalized Is Hurting My Eyes". I don't want any editing stats, but refusing this edit and claiming the edit as unnecessary is a little weird, isn't it?

Comment: @ErtürkÖztürk - No, we're talking about refusing edits that simply arbitrarily change one word from lowercase to uppercase which is not a proper name.  A copywriter would look at those edits and reject them purely on the basis that they are incorrect.  Changing the words from all capitalization to lowercase isn't incorrect, so it's more of a grey area.  If someone changes those, I also suggest fixing other problems they see to minimize the chances of edits being rejected.  Hope this helps clarify.