# "Too minor" reason to reject an edit has been removed

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits

Recently (but I admit I didn't review edits for some time) I noticed that *"Too minor"* reject reason for an editing has been dropped (specifically I was about to reject [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7281251)).

Now we have *"No improvement whatsoever"* but I don't know if it applies: a minor edit IS an improvement, [too little](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271358/1207195) but still present.

In short: should we use *"No improvement whatsoever"* also for minor edits or are minor edits now allowed and encouraged?

Comment: It's even more annoying when you (as a reviewer) want to *expand* on these "too minor" edits,  but *reject* the original edit for being crap. Now, you can **either** build upon the edit *but have to approve it*, or **reject** the edit, but then have to start off from the original post.

Comment: That's already since [Oct 2014](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/10/new-editing-badges-and-enhancements-to-suggested-edits/).

Comment: @nicael thank you for the link! Even reading that I'm still in doubt about what I should do :(

Comment: @elizion yes, that! 

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti Lol yes, . But for a minor edit like mine, wouldn't you agree that it does make the question easier to understand?

Comment: @Elizion I agree minor edits will improve questions, no doubt about that (especially when OP isn't native English speaker). My perplexity is because they were _usually/often_ rejected (and they had a specific close reason) because an edit had  to address multiple (major) issues. My question is: "Are they now _officially_ allowed?"

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti That I can't tell you. In my opinion, there is a difference between a minor edit doing something rather substantial (*i.e. fixing the question structure so it doesn't trip up people trying to understand the question*) and a minor edit fixing subtle grammar mistakes that are extremely easy to read past,  like the one you linked to.

Comment: I was torn about an edit to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31705248/java-string-vs-stream#31705387) that simply changed the indenting of the code. Normally, proper indenting greatly improves readability, so I'm all in favor of it, but in this case it was simply changing from one style of perfectly readable indenting to another. I wanted to reject as "no improvement whatsoever" but the harsh wording (particularly the last little bit) dissuaded me. (The edit moved the `catch` to the same indent level as `try`, but I don't think it improved readability at all.)

Comment: @ted I agree and I still don't know what to do. Often I...just skip them...

Comment: I would still like some direction on this issue.. As many comments have stated, I constantly run into very minor edits, usually things like capitalization. I've been marking them as "no improvement whatsoever", but every time I do, I feel a little dirty, because technically, there was an improvement, it was just extremely minor and didn't affect the readability of the question/answer in any way.