# A moderator messaged me that my edits which only remove "thanks" and alike are discouraged

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits

There are threads here ([thread 1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290019/user-spamming-edits-removing-only-thanks) and [thread 2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302300/should-we-approve-suggested-edits-that-just-remove-thanks)) already but in my opinion it needs further discussion.

1. **It is discouraged, but not a punishable violation?**

   I can remember when I didn't have the privilege to 'instant edit' on SO. I always removed "thanks" and salutations and greetings and people always voted for it to be approved.
2. **Why is it discouraged if the majority of people seem(ed) to approve of it?**

   In my opinion even removing "thanks" or something makes a post more useful. It is shorter and I bet a lot of people find it more pleasing and professional. Because this is what SO is for me: A professional community of programmers.
3. **Additionally, the OP learns from this mistake and may not do it in the future. What do you think?**

   Quote from the moderator:

   > Please do not edit posts only to make such trivial edits. If there is
   >   nothing to improve about the substance of the post, it's better to
   >   just leave it alone.
4. **Consider the post is perfect except for a "thanks" at the end. Am I doing wrong then removing it?**
5. **If the bumping up of the post is a major problem, shouldn't we change when a post is bumped up or incorparate a 'major edit' switch? This way the post is only bumped if the switch was activated.**
6. **See my edits for yourself, they are public (for the one's who don't know). Does the majority make sense or not?**
   https://stackoverflow.com/users/1788806/progressive-overload?tab=activity&sort=revisions

Comment: Your edits no longer need to be approved but that doesn't mean that they don't get reviewed anymore.  The edit re-activates the Q+A and puts it back on people's front page so they can have a look at it.  Which is pretty precious real estate on a site with so many new questions that need answers.  You are not only wasting people's time by having to review the edit, you are also preventing new questions from being visible.  It is therefore imperative that your edit is worthwhile, just removing "thanks" doesn't cut it.

Comment: Maybe there should be a switch... the editor can set which determines whether the post is bumped or not. If "thanks" is the only thing wrong with a post... I see reason to edit, regardless what happens and if I look at the provided answers they seem to only criticise that one ONLY edits thanks regardless if there are other problems or not.

Comment: Abuse prevention is one big reason why edits need to be reviewed, clearly such a switch doesn't help that.  The best place for that switch is between people's ears, just follow the guidance provided by the moderator.  You were supposed to learn all this when you still had less than 2000 rep btw.  How did that go wrong?  Did reviewers approve such small edits before?

Comment: @HansPassant sure they did... but instead of attacking what is between my ears, you should think about what went wrong in the big picture. I try to understand and learn. No need to be rude. I consider your comment offensive.

Comment: @progressive_overload you want a spam switch? I don't think we're going to have one of those. Spammers will create innocuous posts (probably plagiarised) and then edit them into spam. We'll find it hard to track that if they aren't bumped. People will then come across spam as they search for stuff.

Comment: @HansPassant "Did reviewers approve such small edits before?" Yes. People even click "Approve" on the audits in the SE queue. Not just once, but repeatedly. And those are the audits that are generated instead of selected.

Comment: "Maybe there should be a switch... the editor can set which determines whether the post is bumped or not." Stack Overflow tries to minimize the number of choices you have to make. They won't add GUI elements unless they are deemed really necessary. The idea, I believe, is to keep the interface intuitive and clean.

Comment: @S.L.Barth clean... exactly what a post is after you remove "thanks". :)

Comment: @HansPassant  The argument about the precious real estate holds true of course. I don't understand that point about reviews though. How are edits, that take mere seconds to review, going to be a problem for reviewers or jam any queue?

Comment: One of the bigger ideas of edit review queue is that the editor gets feedback from the reviewers, learning how to do it properly.  Not a "queue jam" issue.  If reviewers don't reject "thanks" removal edits then, sure, that goal isn't quite achieved.  Not so sure it is a real issue, there is an unhealthy 100% success rate expectation in reviewing and that is an impossible goal.

Comment: @HansPassant Mostly agreed (voting comment up). I don't think a 100% success rate is expected, but the current success rate for reviewing is still too low. It's been worse though - there is a gradual improvement. We're just not where we should be yet.

Comment: If you feel systematically removing "thanks" from posts is a valuable investment of your time, I'd suggest that you have too much time.

Comment: In any case bumping is **not** a major problem. If it were we wouldn't be able to see new posts when doing searches due to all the bumping of old questions. Also, bumping an old question sometimes may let people add alternative/improved solutions that might not have been available when asked, so a bump isn't often a uniquely negative thing.

Comment: [a couple of posts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287666/too-minor-reason-to-reject-an-edit-has-been-removed) about [too minor edits from the old days](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253326/too-minor-edits-better-to-leave-poor-quality-on-the-site) to add to the "Linked" list

Comment: @Arjan that is an absurd argument that isn't accurate by any probe to the  data [How to deal with serial tag-only edits from Sub 2k users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/314573)

Comment: @HansPassant *The edit re-activates the Q+A* So why not fix that, instead of using it as a reason for not doing edits which may not be semantically meaningful but nevertheless improve the quality of the question and by extension the site?

Comment: In addition to @HansPassant's comments, it also pushes closed question in to the reopen queue. Too often do I see questions pushed there with useless edits that *only* have "thanks" removed by someone who absolutely cannot bear to stand this apparent insult on a *closed* question. This deprives the OP from the opportunity to actually make meaningful edits to fix the post and get it in the reopen queue.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker well, who said that the OP was editing closed (actually only on hold has this feature) questions?

Comment: #5 simply doesn't work, because then I can go around editing all the `uint32_t`s I see by deleting the `i` and prepending a `c`, and no-one will see it for a long time.

Comment: The moderator is wrong. Continue improving the site please. However, you may also exercise prudence in determining whether an edit is worthwhile *enough* to warrant bringing that post back to the front page, if it is an old (or low-quality) question.

Comment: @TylerH I don't agree (well not completely anyway.) If all you are doing is editing old posts to remove "thanks", then that is *not worth doing*. I think it's perfectly valid to do on new posts, or old posts that have some value and need other things fixing too.

Comment: @DavidG I those old posts have value to me... it is worth editing them as if they were new, because I faced a problem which was solved by an old post. I am not systematically searching for old posts to remove their salutations... :D

Comment: @progressive_overload Put it this way: does removing "thanks" actually improve anything? Does it improve it enough to bump a post to the front page where everyone gets to see it again?

Comment: Note that I'm not saying it's necessarily a bad thing to do it, but is it really worth your time? There's tonnes of other things that can be done to make things better round here!

Comment: Consensus here seems to be fix everything wrong with a post yet on ym meta post here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/327780/how-to-make-2k-users-make-better-edits it was if you're over 2K rep you don't have too, I think the community really needs to decide what they want.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder I like the idea to make a post incrementally better... it's like writing a program. every commit adds features or fixes bugs. This does not mean that I intentionally leave out corrections I could have made with my knowledge and just remove "thx". The only problem is the 'bump'. Without the bump we wouldn't have this discussion in the first place. Because yes, only removing salutations, makes a post significantely better in my eyes.

Comment: @progressive_overload That comment was directed at everyone not you in particular

Comment: @TheLethalCoder I know... i wanted to reply anyways.. pls read my comment edit. Quite an impressive number of downvotes you harvested on your thread. I really don't see why. discussion is always good.

Comment: @HansPassant Sorry, I think I'm misunderstanding something. You consider the *front page questions list* to be a *review queue*?

Comment: "Thanks" or similar expressions have nothing to do with technical issues or writing mistakes or anything relevant. They are irrelevant. Just a social formality. Therefore, what you are doing is useless. I don't know if there is any reputation involved in those edits, though.

Comment: If removing 'thanks' from a post pollutes the front page, this seems like a flaw in the design of the front page, rather than a reason not to edit the post.

Comment: I believe technology can help. Remove salutations/greetings/thank yous that are by themselves from the last few lines :) Yes, it will never be foolproof, but a simple solution would go very far for this case. Just pop up a message educating people, and if the salutation or thank you message is still there after submission, delete it!.

Comment: @jwg You're putting this sideways, removing the bigger picture. Edited posts are bumped to the front page. Removing thanks is an edit. An edit is activity on a post. The flaw is in your demagogic way of putting this, not in the fact that active posts are bumped to the front page.

Comment: Bumping isn't a problem. It isn't long after a question is "bumped" before it's fallen back down below other, newer content again. Improving questions is good; "thanks" and greetings don't belong here. Please continue improving questions. Cheers.

Comment: Back when I used to do a lot of "thanks" cleanup, I'd have been insulted if you told me I couldn't clean up. I'd have said something about how engineers are supposed to solve problems, and go add me a damned 10k "don't bump me" flag. Could be why I'm not missed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Too minor" edits - better to leave poor quality on the site?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253326/too-minor-edits-better-to-leave-poor-quality-on-the-site)

Comment: @Henke yes it is a good addition. Thanks!

Answer (score 154, accepted):

As the moderator who sent the message, I will try to answer your questions and clarify my request. *Everyone who is not OP, please note: the quotation in the question is not my entire message to OP. The full message was significantly longer and attempted to make most of the points that follow.*

**TL;DR** The problem is that you are both seeking out posts, sometimes very old ones, to edit *and* only making very trivial edits. This bumps old posts to the home page for no real reason, which disadvantages (1) new questions, (2) new answers, and (3) more significant edits.

Minor edits, particularly on brand-new posts, are often fine. **It's only a problem when you are (1) *looking* for these kinds of things to edit, (2) *only* making those minor edits, *and* (3) failing to edit other problems with a post.**

---

## Background

In a nutshell:

- Your editing activity drew a flag from another user.
- It was a custom flag.
- Custom flags take roughly 10x more time than standard flags because they almost always require much more investigation. This means we *do* investigate, but we have to limit the investigation somehow. You have done well over 1,100 edits, so I'm not going to look at all of those. I'm going to pick a sample of recent edits and see if it looks like a problem.
- I investigated and found that you had, in fact, made lots of recent, trivial edits. For example, in [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25391126/android-sqliteopenhelper-time-consuming-oncreate-need-progress-bar-on-first-run) you missed a typo and some awkward grammar. [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25391126/android-sqliteopenhelper-time-consuming-oncreate-need-progress-bar-on-first-run/25394668#25394668) had lots of issues, like incorrect formatting, an inline URL that should probably be linked text, some awkward sentences, and an unnecessary "EDIT:." But the only change you made was to remove

  > I hope that helps!
  >
  > Mark
- Some of these edits were on very old posts, often very low-scoring old posts, which made it look like you were looking for things to edit based on certain phrases, not just stumbling across some posts that needed editing. And some of your edits were arguably inappropriate, anyway, because they changed the meaning of the post, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/12155874/revisions).
- Again, I didn't check all of your edits. I looked at the last dozen or so at the time.
- I agreed with the flagger that something was amiss, so I needed to do something about it.
- A mod message is the easiest, fastest, clearest means at my disposal in that scenario to contact you directly and let you know that something is going wrong.

## Your questions

> (1) So, this is discouraged, but it is not a punishable violation?

Yes, it's discouraged. Generally, it's not going to lead to a suspension or anything more severe.

I say "generally" because there are always exceptions. The [first Meta discussion you linked to above](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290019/user-spamming-edits-removing-only-thanks), for example, shows an extreme abuse of the editing system. If that kind of thing continues *after* a moderator has stepped in, yes, it could theoretically result in a suspension. Similarly, if you were to set up a bot to abuse the API and make these edits by the hundreds or thousands, you can expect to hear from one of us, and we will almost certainly issue a suspension just to stop the behavior until we can talk to you.

> (2) Why is it discouraged if the majority of people seem(ed) to like it?

To be clear, it's not that people "liked" your edits; they *approved* them, which is different. Some reviewers don't do a great job and will approve literally anything they see (see [robo-reviewing](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256231/review-ban-progressive-system)). As SO legend and former moderator Bill the Lizard explained in the [second Meta discussion you mentioned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/302301/2057919),

> A simple "thanks in advance" does not get in the way of the rest of the question when it's all the way at the end of a post (unlike salutations at the beginning), so I don't think it's worth suggesting an edit only to remove a "thanks."
>
> I could understand if people removed "thanks in advance" once in a while when they happened upon it while answering questions, but to search for the phrase and remove it in bulk seems a bit excessive. That's wasting the time of suggested edit reviewers.

Lots of bad edits get through the review process. That indicates a problem with the review process, not that the edits are necessarily okay.

You wrote,

> In my opinion even removing "thanks" or something makes a post more useful. It is shorter and I bet a lot of people find it more pleasing and professional. Because this is what SO is for me: A professional community of programmers.

Sure, but not if you are bumping lots of old posts to the home page for trivial reasons. The marginal value of removing the word "thanks" is very low.

> (3) Additionally, the OP learns from this mistake and may not do it in the future. What do you think?

Okay, but that doesn't mean you should do trivial edits. Remove the excess verbiage *and* fix all other issues with the post.

> (4) Consider the post is perfect except for a "thanks" at the end. Am I doing wrong then removing it?

Yes, if (1) there are other issues that you didn't fix or (2) you are going looking for posts to edit in this way. There's no need to dredge up old posts only to remove the word "thanks," especially if there's more that should be addressed. See the quote from Bill the Lizard above.

> (5) If the bumping up of the post is a major problem. Shouldn't we change when a post is bumped up or incorparate a 'major edit' switch? This way the post is only bumped if the switch was activated.

This would be a disaster, as several other folks have pointed out. It would lead to lots more spam, defacement, and other issues. If we leave the switch up to the editor, it will be abused. If we try to automate it, it will create a tremendous amount of work for the developers and very likely break a lot of posts unintentionally. **The better policy is the one we have: encourage *substantive* editing, so that *every* edit is one that merits bumping the post back to the home page.**

---

In short, please just go easy on the edit system. If a post is worth editing, it's worth editing in full, not just to remove a relatively harmless "thanks" or "hope that helps." The occasional edit like that is harmless, but doing lots of them is a cause for concern.

Comment: Thank u very much! Still I don't get anything out of my edits except for making SO a better place, no matter how trivial my edits are. I don't earn reputation, not even badges. So, I still don't see the harm and as you see many don't too. As you can also see nothing was automated. That posts are bumped up is not my fault, it is the system's. And saying that I only edited old irrelevant posts does also not hold true since they would have been deleted then. Additionally, who is to say what is for whom important?

Comment: @progressive_overload We do appreciate that you want to make SO better! Very much, in fact. The problem isn't that your edits aren't helpful. It's that the very minor edits aren't helpful *enough* in light of the side effects (bumping posts, encouraging others to make trivial edits, and so on).

Comment: @progressive_overload By the way, one clarification. You said, "And saying that I only edited old irrelevant posts does also not hold true since they would have been deleted then." That's not correct. Posts don't get deleted just for being old. Posts are only deleted automatically if they receive lots of certain types of flags (spam, abusive) or are closed for certain reasons and for a long time.

Comment: I also said irrelevant :D. Thanks anyways for the discussion!

Comment: A moderator once told me that I should never worry about bumping a post by doing an edit. I don't remember who or when, it was several years ago.

Comment: @Stijn That's good advice, if it's a substantive edit, but not if it's trivial. That's the reason we have a minimum number of characters changed for edits by users without the edit privilege, for example: we don't want to bump the post because, say, someone deleted an extra line break. Don't worry at all about the bump *if you're doing substantive editing*, but please do think twice if all you're doing is removing "Thanks" or similar wording.

Comment: I tend to find old posts when I search for questions, and most of the time they have trivial but, in the context that Q&A should be of the highest quality possible, important issues which detriment the general quality of the post.

Comment: "That's the reason we have a minimum number of characters changed" There is no minimum for users with the editing privilege.

Comment: @JoshCaswell True, but the point is that discouraging trivial edits is why we have that limit for low-rep users. By the time users have the editing privilege, they've hopefully figured out how to edit responsibly. A single-character edit can sometimes be extremely helpful (think, fixing busted formatting), but the rule is in place for low-rep users to teach them the *kind* of edits that are appropriate.

Comment: Why should editing a post bump it, anyway?

Comment: @bd33 This draws attention to posts that have gone from bad to good or that have new and important information. It also helps us catch edits that introduce spam, deface posts, or are otherwise bad. See this MSE post for more info: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/23242/238426

Comment: Your answer to (4) is a little off, as he specifically mentions a post that is `perfect except for a "thanks" at the end`. Other than that, great answer!

Comment: @FabioTurati Yes, but that post is an **old one** that doesn't need bumping to the front page unless it needed substantial editing, so the point stands. Ed clearly states *"There's no need to dredge up old posts only to remove the word "thanks""*.

Comment: @Lankymart still, the "front page" doesn't act like an /active tab, see http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/stack-overflow-homepage-changes/ [Help us choose a sort order for the Stack Overflow homepage](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/69571) [Help us choose a sort order for the Stack Overflow homepage](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/69571)

Comment: @EdCottrell "This one had lots of issues, like incorrect formatting..." at least he found that post organically as can be seen by [its comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25391126/android-sqliteopenhelper-time-consuming-oncreate-need-progress-bar-on-first-run/25394668#comment65540718_25394668). He wasn't hunting things to edit, just looking for answers and editing as he came across them.

Comment: @Braiam re that post: okay, that's fair. Again, we only have so much time to investigate these things, and I saw a pattern across multiple edits. And it's worth repeating that wouldn't issue a suspension for something like that; this was just a heads-up regarding the pattern.

Comment: That's the thing... there wasn't any pattern here *that a moderator needs to be involved*. If the user was so annoyed by the edits, why wasn't its first solution trying to communicate with the editor in question, instead of escalating the issue? I think that should be more gentle than immediately send a scary moderator message, don't you agree?

Comment: @Braiam First, there is a pattern of lots of these edits. They become problematic at some point, no matter why they were made. Second, I can't speak for the flagger, but flagging this was perfectly fine. That's why we have moderators; not everything can or should be handled by "ordinary" users. That's one reason we can send direct messages, even though other users can't.  As for the "scary moderator message," I really don't think, "Hey, take it easy," is that scary. I  tried to be gentle in the message I sent. Publicly calling out an editor is more awkward than a private message, not less.

Comment: The only pattern I see is that OP found them organically, which isn't a bad thing. You in your answer say "It's only a problem when you are (1) looking for these kinds of things to edit, (2) only making those minor edits, and (3) failing to edit other problems with a post." the only thing that fits OP behavior is the third one (the second seems to me a subcategory of the third, not sure why you separated them). Not enough to merit "moderator intervention". BTW, a comment wouldn't provoked this metaQ which made the issue more public that a single comment would.

Comment: @Braiam (1) There is a pattern of a lot of these edits, regardless of how OP found them. (2) When it's enough to start drawing flags, we have to investigate and act *as best we can* given the fact that we are volunteers with limited time. (3) A minor edit and an incomplete edit are distinct things. (4) A comment might not provoke this question, but it would be *me* calling out *OP* publicly. OP's choice to bring it up publicly is very different. (5) **That's all I have to say about this. I've tried to explain why I sent the message. The discussion is not really constructive at this point.**

Answer (score 66):

The point is that you need to fix **everything** that's wrong with a post when you edit it.

Blindly going though and fixing one thing still leaves work for the rest of us to fix all the other issues.

If you don't have edit privileges, you're asking a group of people to club together to review your edit. They deserve not to have to further edit every post they review don't they?

We can't have a switch to not bump posts as that will be abused

- spammers will use it to hide spam by creating an initial innocuous (probably plagiarised) post which they later edit into spam. Detecting this will be harder
- detecting people who deface their posts will be harder too

Comment: what if there is nothing else wrong? Consider, I edit 15 posts... the only problem they have is "thanks"... some greetings and salutations...

Comment: That's extremely unlikely.

Comment: But if so, no problem?

Comment: "Please do not edit posts only to make such trivial edits. If there is nothing to improve about the substance of the post, it's better to just leave it alone." quote from the moderator. I don't know if I can disclose his complete message!?

Comment: @progressive_overload: You can if you want.

Comment: @progressive_overload I believe the moderator simply wanted to avoid you from bumping every other post just because you want to remove the thanks. As far as you don't go into a hunt for searching all these posts you're okay. I personally edit out such noise if I encounter such a question, but I don't think this is a problem because the chances of finding a question with the "thanks etc." line and where everything else is fine are slim, and in all other cases you aren't just editing that line out.

Comment: @progressive_overload Maybe if moderator didn't find out you **do ignore** other problems (and he did, as mentioned in other answer), he wouldn't contact you. But you did edit posts without fixing even the most obvious problems. Multiple times.

Comment: @progressive_overload If the presence of an extraneous "thanks" is *all* that's wrong with the post, then the post has no problems. Be glad it's a good question and move on. Removing "thanks" isn't a substantive improvement all by itself. Something you haven't thought about is the reverse question of yours: what harm does an extra "thanks" do?

Comment: The point here is *"everything"* is different depending on the editor, let's just say it needs to be a **substantial** edit.

Answer (score 27):

Removing "thanks" and salutations is good, but only as part of a larger edit that addresses every problem with a post.

If you don't have full edit privileges (< 2000 points), then your edit must be reviewed, and you get +2 if it's approved. However, some users have used these extremely minor edits to farm rep. Which is one reason why this is frowned upon.

Another issue, applicable for all users regardless of rep, is that edits bump a post. We don't want posts bumped to the front page just because somebody removed "Thanks in advance".

A final reason is historical. It used to be that too many edits rendered a post Community Wiki. This is no longer the case.

Try to make your edit substantial - fix everything with a post, to the best of your ability.

> Why is it discouraged if the majority of people seem(ed) to like it?

Many reviewers blindly click "Approve" on everything they encounter. Instead of further editing or rejecting as they should. These sloppy reviewers have given you the wrong impression.

On closing, removing "thanks", "hello", etc from edits is not normally something that users get punished for. But if that is the only change you make, when there is more to fix - then it's frowned upon.

I [proposed a FAQ for editors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303219/812149). It's not official, but it should give you some ideas of what else you can do to improve a post, beyond removing salutations.

Comment: What about my 4th question?

Comment: @progressive_overload If the post is perfect except for a "Thanks"? Just leave it. It's usually not worth bumping a post for.

Comment: ok, but isn't another question then if the bumping system is flawed?

Comment: @progressive_overload I was just thinking about that, too! I guess SO could often detect if an edit merely removed salutations.. but that it's not worth the extra work required. If I were SO, it would not be very high on my priority list - if it was there at all.

Comment: @S.L.Barth I disagree with that. The number of such posts is so low that bumping a few of them doesn't really matter and it is sometimes useful to have an older post bumped up, so maybe improved answers can be added by new people. The only thing to make sure is that your edit is fixing everything on the post and to avoid "hunting" for such posts just to perform these edits.

Comment: I disagree. If farming rep is a problem, then maybe the +2 rep gain should disappear. If bumping is a problem, then edits should not bump posts (or one should be able to mark an edit as minor that not bump them). When I review, I accept minor edits if the post has high qualitity. I may reject or improve an edit if it's too minor. (I have more a problem with people editting low quality posts instead of flagging them for closure/deletion.)

Comment: @k0pernikus I'm increasingly convinced that the +2 for edits is a bad idea. IIRC it has been requested once and was massively voted against... but I wasn't able to find the proposal back. I'll grant that the occassional bump won't hurt. The problem arises when many posts get bumped for cosmetic edits.

Comment: @k0pernikus notice that OP has 2k by the time the edits were made, so reputation wasn't a motivator.

Answer (score 24):

> Please do not edit posts only to make such trivial edits. If there is nothing to improve about the substance of the post, it's better to just leave it alone.

I disagree. I don't go out of my way to search for them, but when I come across a post that has such fluff and is otherwise OK, I still edit it out.

I'm really curious why it's "better to just leave it alone", what harm could it possibly do?

Comment: exactly, my point of view!

Comment: There's a difference between "coming across" a post that has fluff like "thanks" etc and actively seeking them out. The former will result in a few edits spread out over the day. The latter will result in lots of edits in a short time. Also even if you "come across" such a post you should look at fixing as much as you can.

Comment: @BoltClock If think the problem they have is not the review queue but the fact that those posts are bumped to the front page as active.

Comment: @progressive_overload Then the bumping mechanism maybe should change.

Comment: @k0pernikus this is exactly my point :) see my 5th question pls

Comment: @k0pernikus you can change ordering in lists however you like but you will still be updating the activity date on old posts despite no technical activity. While noisy in the positive case, non-activity is a good negative factor for instable frameworks, libraries and languages. Spending the weekend correcting javascript to JavaScript would be a great way to drive a whole community away from researching problems using this site (and/or double up on the problem of poorly researched duplicates.)

Comment: @k0pernikus If we are to change the bumping mechanism, how will we bump questions that have had substantive updates that clarify a question and make it better, but not edits that remove fluff?

Answer (score 18):

I find that the reasoning exposed here are using the right arguments to push wrong conclusions:

> The point is that you need to fix everything that's wrong with a post when you edit it.

Yes. That's the point. I agree with that, but when you couple it with:

> Blindly going though and fixing one thing still leaves work for the rest of us to fix all the other issues.

Supposes that the user wasn't fixing anything else or that there was something else to fix. There have been times where we tell editors to "no polish turds", well, what if OP found non-turds to polish? Damned if you do, damned if you don't seems an apt saying here.

Other absurd is that:

> We don't want posts bumped to the front page just because somebody removed "Thanks in advance".

The "front page" takes into account a mix of every tag you ever answered and is favorite and some random posts, all at random. Even if I go to javascript tag and edit all the latest 50 questions at most you will have 3 questions mixed in the +60 of the home page. Stack Overflow is ginormous! There is a question asked every second! Your front page has enough questions to take from that you won't see a bunch of posts edited by the same user (if you use the new nav this is doubly true).

The only ones that would have some problems are the users that hang out in /active for specific tags and given that there's no evidence that the user edited all the posts within a tag, I find that not an issue.

For science, I searched all the posts that would appear if you search for search for posts that contain "thank you" by relevance... [of the top 15](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22thank%20you%22), 7 are php and they are using "thank you" in an organic way, not as a courtesy kind of thing. I don't find how the OP would have find posts with thank you's to edit that would actually upset someone question list, and in the case it does then that says some worrying things about the users asking questions.

---

Since everyone presumes OP did a bunch of edits in a short amount of time, I searched for the edits that it did that are more than 2 days old to 7 days old, thats it 5 days, and where a thanks was involved:

- https://stackoverflow.com/posts/38497884/timeline https://stackoverflow.com/posts/38498037/revisions (edits to both, q and a)
- https://stackoverflow.com/posts/39094804/timeline
- https://stackoverflow.com/posts/25391126/timeline and https://stackoverflow.com/posts/25394668/revisions
- https://stackoverflow.com/posts/39033689/timeline

Only 4 edits that involved a removal of a "thanks", in **5 days**. The OP obviously *wasn't hunting these down*. Of the three bumped posts that happened the same day, the spacing between the bumps was 1, 4, 1, 1 minutes. The bumps that were spaced by 1 minute, is because the OP edited both, question and answer, and the answer was edited first (apparently he was looking for something), and of the three at least one was asked the same day.

Conclusion:

- OP doesn't hunt down post to edit "thanks" out.
- When he edit them, it isn't the only thing he does.
- Apparently it was an android follower the one that flagged
- The android tag has 1 active question every 36 second (the latest 100 active questions were active in the last hour)
- The spacing between edits would at most cause a slight denser than usual activity period, but this isn't weird for the tag, as there could be 3 active posts in less than a minute and no active post for two minutes spans.

Comment: I don't watch the front page; I watch a search for a bunch of tags with reasonable question volume (like `[x86]` and `[assembly]`), sorted by "active".  So edit-spam in any of the tags I watch absolutely does pollute my SO.  I don't want to drink from the [c] / [c++] / [linux] firehose, even though I know those languages and nearly have a C++ gold badge.  The front page would make me crazy, because I can't deal with questions coming faster than I can look at them. Anyway, I have had this happen before, with a user searching for and fixing broken-English phrases even in useless old questions.

Comment: The [front page](http://stackoverflow.com) actually doesn't have the fire-hose problem. Assuming you've set up favorite and ignored tags, or have answered enough questions that SO can reasonably [predict the tags you're interested in](http://stackoverflow.com/users/prediction-data), the front page shows a smattering of recently-active questions with those tags. There is no auto-update, but manually refreshing will get you a slightly different list of questions. It's very vulnerable to mass edits. The fire-hose problem exists only on the Newest page, which is unfiltered and basically useless.

Comment: @PeterCordes who said that **OP edited all questions from the same sets of tags?** No one, knows exactly which questions were edited that prompted that response... it could be just 2 questions!

Comment: @CodyGray err, no. The home page doesn't sort by active, so that's not an issue [Why do some recently asked questions not show up in the question list?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/138366), and even then, nobody knows which editions prompted this kind of response.

Comment: @Braiam: nobody said that OP edited questions all or mostly from the same tags.  But people that do things like this do usually end up bumping a couple questions in the same tag, and that's annoying for me, especially when the questions are garbage that just never got closed and should have been left to rot (like in the case I'm thinking of, not this OP).  Bothering a lot of people a small amount instead of me personally a whole lot is still problematic, and totally not worth it just to remove a "thanks".  The higher quality the question, the more justified/useful a minor edit is, though.

Comment: @PeterCordes then check the /newest... I sometimes end up editing questions in the same tag because I'm looking for an answer to a problem and didn't find the solution. If that annoy you, maybe you should not use SE which explicitly favors editing [**If you see something that needs improvement, click edit!**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/editing)

Comment: Seeing bumped questions is a small price to pay for the improvements that edits bring, unless the question is garbage.  For some old&bad questions, the only real improvement possible is to get it closed+deleted.  Removing a "thanks" from a useless FAQ / homework question isn't an improvement, it's still useless.  You're trying to make it sound like I'm arguing against editing anything ever.

Comment: @PeterCordes for your amusement, I looked at the posts edited by OP. None were plain "garbage" (if you ignore they are android, I think they are not that below the average question), and he didn't only edited "thanks" out, it also improved the answers.

Comment: Good, then that's less bad than the person I talked to that was making similar minor edits even to bad questions, fixing common non-native-English grammar mistakes even in useless questions.  IDK what your point is, though, because this meta question is about the merits of making trivial edits that *only* remove a "thanks", or something like that.  Not just judging the OP.

Comment: @PeterCordes that ship sailed when this happened [No Thanks, Damn It!](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/288160)

Comment: This answer represents what is, in my opinion, a complete bullsh*t attitude. I disagree with the majority of this answer for so many reasons, all of which I have iterated time and again, and others have iterated here repeatedly. It saddens me that this nonsensical mentality exists at all.

Comment: @TinyGiant yeah, the opposite is nothing better. I prefer U&L way of doing things: quality above everything, [even the authors if necessary](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4414/41104). That's what we should strive. Personal preferences should be relegated to the last place and only that which we are sure will work for eons to come should stay.

Comment: @Braiam: I like the way you see it most, that's why I marked your answer as "the answer", but after some thinking I think the moderator's answer should be seen first. Since there is no reputation loss in it, I don't think it is a problem. Thank you!

Comment: @WilliMentzel well, by accepting the answer you are basically accepting their views, rather than what you consider it's the best for the community. And if something I've learn is that most people take the "first answer" as the undeniable truth. If you want to change anything, you should start by not being conformist with the way things are.

Comment: @WilliMentzel now that user isn't a moderator anymore. See what I was getting at?

Comment: @Braiam yes, I see. Also, I don't know the circumstances. Have more info on that?

Answer (score 9):

Stack Overflow's "war on thanks" has baffled me for quite some time, what harm does saying "thank you" do? But more importantly, there are some side-effects to edits:

- People get annoyed by this, which is really not a strange thing. I understand that Stack Overflow is an attempt to build a useful library of knowledge (and is not a free tutor service), but it *is* doing it in a Q&A format, which *does* mean you're asking strangers on the internet for help. [I have argued this at some length elsewhere](https://vi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1330/51), and I'll not repeat it here.
- Closed questions that get edited get pushed to the reopen queue *once* and *once* only. Too often do I see questions pushed there with useless edits that only have "thanks" removed by someone who absolutely cannot bear to stand this apparent insult on a *closed* question. This deprives the OP from the (usually last) opportunity to redeem their question and actually make meaningful edits to fix the post and get it reopened.

  This only applies to closed questions, but unfortunately it's far too common.
- It pushes questions to the front page. This is not necessarily a bad thing if the edits are meaningful, but removing "thanks" isn't. Has the question been significantly clarified or otherwise improved to such a degree that it might invite new answers or upvotes? If the answer to that is "no" then the edit probably isn't worthwhile (tag edits are except from this by the way, as they are almost always useful).

  Remember that "pushing to the frontpage" means "preventing another question from appearing there" and that many people answer questions from the frontpage.
- Similarly, it pushes the questions the top of the tag's "active" list.
- If you have less than 2k reputation, your edits get reviewed. There is a long review backlog of thousands of reviews. Is removing "thanks" *really* so important that we need to add to it?

If you really feel that someone saying "thank you" is a huge problem, then well, go ahead and remove it if you must (I don't see the use, but ah well), but edits that **only** remove "thanks" contribute to more "fluff" in the system than they're (allegedly) removing.

Comment: +1. The Reopening had not been mentioned in the other answers and is an important consideration.

Comment: "Closed questions that get edited get pushed to the reopen queue once and once only." Only **on hold** questions have this feature. Otherwise it won't.

Comment: "It pushes questions to the front page" The front page isn't an issue. It selects several *random posts* on random tags with preference to your favorite tags (there's the tag prediction too), which makes unlikely that you will see more than 4 posts edited by the same user, even if it's done in a short amount of time.

Comment: "There is a long review backlog of thousands of reviews." The queue can't have more than 200 active pending review, and even then, the peak of [suggested edits in a UTC day have been 2535](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/422783#graph) in the last 180 days, which gives us a ~105 suggested edits by hour, in a peak day. So **this is entire false and misguiding**. Suggested edits in average get approved in less than an hour.

Comment: @Braiam [This seems like thousands to me](http://i.stack.imgur.com/3hbhD.png). You're right that the *edit* queue is usually much smaller, but I was talking about "reviews" in general, not just "edit reviews". People doing edit reviews are not doing $other reviews, so it adds to the general workload. As for the front page, I have often clicked a seemingly interesting question to answer on the front page, only to find out it was well over a year old and bumped there just because someone made a useless edit; the fact that the front-page isn't swamped doesn't mean it's not a  problem at all.

Comment: First, "I have often clicked a seemingly interesting question to answer" You were informed how many answers it had, if any was accepted, the score, views, etc. **up front**, that seems a weak reasoning for me. Don't be dissuaded to not answer just because the question is *"old"*, play the long game instead! And, the fact that there are some queues that have more pending reviews is irrelevant. We are talking about edits, so that the close queue is up to almost 10k again is not important in this context.

Comment: *"Thanks"* and other fluff personalises the question and tends to encourage a more relaxed style like you would find in most forums which I don't think should be encouraged and detracts from the question being posed.

Answer (score 9):

**Foreword:**
As you can see, I am the OP (original poster) of the question above. Here my view of things after considering your answers and comments.

I am really impressed how much discussion this topic sparked. So much different opinions. One would think SO exists long enough to have dealt with such a simple problem. Seems like this is not so simple after all!

**To my defense:**
See the edits I made and decide for yourself, if it improved SO overall or didn't: https://stackoverflow.com/users/1788806/progressive-overload?tab=activity&sort=revisions

**What I learned from this discussion:** If I edit, I will edit the whole post. Not just the flaw that pops in my eye first. Maybe in the past, I made the mistake to just remove "Thanks" and didn't improve anything else. Maybe because I was below 2000 reputation and I wanted more of it, maybe because I was plain lazy. Let's say, I was young and needed the reputation! ;) (actually if I saw this smiley in a post, I would remove it)

Nevertheless do I believe in making something incrementally better. Everyone is good at something. One of us is good at spelling, the next one knows the difference between two tags.

So, in my eyes we should still support minor edits if it is in the best knowledge of the author, meaning he cannot fix anything else which would be in range of his competence.

**Afterword:** In my eyes I made SO (overall) a better place with my >1000 edits and I will continue to do so with my new knowledge!

Comment: *"So, in my eyes we should still support minor edits if it is in the best knowledge of the author"* Absolutely, as long as it isn't done in such a way that negatively impacts the site or it's users.

Comment: Keep in mind there are a LOT of old bad questions on SO that should have been closed & deleted, but fell through the cracks.   The higher quality the question, the more justified/useful a minor edit is.  For a bad question (e.g. yet another variation on a common homework question or newbie error), seeing it again is just a waste of everyone's time.  SO gets too many questions to perfectly handle all the bad ones, so they're still lurking in the back archives. IMO don't edit bad questions unless you can actually make enough improvement for it to be worth seeing.  (esp. if it has a good answer).

Comment: @PeterCordes sure, I don't think I ever edited a question with less than -1 rep...

Comment: I'm also including 0-score questions with trivial answers that were answered quickly and then everyone moved on, instead of actually finding a good duplicate and getting it closed as a duplicate.  Issues like this are why it's encouraged to only edit a question when you came across it and read it because its content was useful or interesting to you, *not* because a text search for "thanks" or common grammar mistakes found it.  (Another part of that reasoning is that you'll have read and understood it enough to be able to improve it meaningfully, e.g. reword a clumsy sentence.)

Comment: Thanks for asking the question. It generated some interesting commentary. Also, it sounds like it served its purpose and you got some great takeaway points. Thanks for helping to make SO better!

Comment: @EdCottrell thank you too for the discussion! i will consider your advice with every edit from now on.

Answer (score 7):

From my personal experience in most cases, a question that has a "Thanks" falls into one of the following scenarios

- It is probably a question from a new user and there are many other things that need editing (formatting, tags, formulation).
- Someone 'fixed' most of the issues but forgot to remove 'thanks' ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/39121071/revisions))
- It is a *very* old question and at the time it was posted nobody cared (or maybe it did not receive enough attention) to remove 'thanks'

In the first two cases someone did a trivial edit or did not fix all the errors. So it is not one person's fault.

Generally, I tend to agree with [Stijn's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/333071/2279200).

My approach is to weigh things before editing. If it is a new question (< a day old), I will edit it, and personally I think that giving it a 'bump' is not such an issue in this case, and maybe it is a good thing for new questions to get an additional 'bump'. If the question is old, I will try to find other things to 'fix' as well. Based on my personal criteria (question content), votes and views, I decide if the the edit justifies the 'bump' or not.

Answer (score 1):

Do not waste time removing *thanks* from posts unless they also have other problems. If, while editing a post for other reasons, you notice a *thanks* at the end, then by all means remove it. This, at least, is the rule I follow, and I seem to recall official guidance along these lines (perhaps from Jeff Atwood?) some time in the past.

Comment: Indeed, [it was Jeff Atwood](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94997/153008). And [again](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/91763/153008). But lots of other people have repeated the same advice.