# Capitalization edits of popular terms in question title as the only edit?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

The exactly same edit suggestion on two different questions got rejected in the first one and accepted in the second.

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15702390
https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15702388

The only thing changed was *`wodpress -> WordPress`*.

Now, this edit is *not* incorrect, does not harm the question in any way and in fact it improves the way the question looks out (however little it does).
On the other hand, it is such a tiny change that it does not deserve its own edit (i.e. I do *not* make such edits).

But since it already *is* an edit, has entered the SO database and there's no way to clean it up, then there's no reason the reject it, is there?
Usually such small edits are rejected (unless supplied with significant other improvements) so I did this, too. Note that they match the `Changes are either completely superfluous` part of the `no improvement whatsoever` reason.

Now I'm not so convinced on either one. What do you think?

Here's a related question, but the answer there addresses the specific user's suggestions the OP asked about: [How to handle edits that are too minor, changing title from uppercase to lowercase?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271317/how-to-handle-edits-that-are-too-minor-changing-title-from-uppercase-to-lowerca)

Comment: I think rejecting those edits is the correct thing to do.

Comment: I think changing `wodpress` to `WordPress` is a valid edit

Comment: If the edit fixes the only major problem in the post, I see no reason to reject it as too minor—that only creates more work for editors and reviewers (or alternatively, leaves posts unfixed). If an edit is minor and doesn't fix glaringly obvious problems, [Reject and Edit it yourself](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/270980/6650102).

Comment: _is a valid edit_  for someone with > 2000 rep. That is too trivial for someone other than that and I would reject it as such if that was the _only_ thing changed.

Comment: @rene, please clarify your comment if it's about Capitalization edits (as in the title of the question) or Spelling edits (as in the given examples).

Comment: @Cœur I meant capitalization fixes. I didn't notice that the examples were fixing spelling mistakes which is less of a problem.

Comment: I did just realize the edits fixed the missing `r` in `wodpress` (thanks to Coeur's edit). I have completely missed them the last ten times I looked at the questions. If I saw them the first time I would have probably approved them since the title is the main part when googling so at least title should be correct.

Comment: Searching for [wodpress](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=wodpress) leads to 22 results. Plenty of options for a new user trying to farm reputation.

Comment: Search for "too minor". This question comes up very often and was discussed in detail already.

Comment: @Zanon hello please its [doesnt](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22doesnt%22) help thanks

Comment: "Too minor" is not a valid rejection reason. If you think there is more to improve, then do so, otherwise - assuming the edit is actually valid - then just approve it.

Comment: @ChristianStrempfer 44 reputation is hardly farming.

Comment: @TylerH It wasn't my intention to blame the OP. I just suggested a different search term s/he might not be aware of.

Answer (score 14):

I agree that capitalization is important for readability, but usually **you shouldn't add tags in titles** ([see more here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles)). In both examples, I believe WordPress is better as a tag than as part of the title. Instead of fixing capitalization, those edits should have removed the word.

> But since it already is an edit, has entered the SO database and
>   there's no way to clean it up, then there's no reason the reject it,
>   is there?

The objective of rejecting those edits is to pass a **clear message** to the user that they should **not** add more edits like that. While some of them have good intentions, most are just trying to farm reputation while wasting the time of reviewers and needlessly bumping posts.

The correct reject reason is:

> **no improvement whatsoever**
>   This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read, easier to find, more accurate or more
>   accessible. **Changes are either completely superfluous** or actively harm
>   readability.

<sup>emphasis mine</sup>

If the user had >2000 rep, fixing capitalization could be a valid edit though if it was a good and popular question with nothing more needing to be fixed.

Comment: Using '[tag] How do I do X?' is discouraged, but I don't think removing the reference to WordPress completely helps with readability. [Titles should be stand-alone summaries of questions *without* depending on tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/180100/titles-should-be-stand-alone-summaries-of-questions-without-depending-on-tags), and a title like 'Searching current Category' alone (from the second example in the OP) would not be at all clear. Ideally, it would be edited to say something like 'How can I search only the current category in WordPress' instead, I think.

Comment: @Aurora0001, as your link and mine explains, you can use tags in titles if it fits organically. *Searching current Category WordPress* is horrible, but *How can I search only the current category in WordPress* is ok. Though, **usually**, we should opt to remove the tag from title and rely on the tag system. If I'm searching about some feature in JavaScript using Google or SO search, I don't want to read 10 times the word JavaScript. Both tools will show results of JavaScript questions even if JS is not in title.

Comment: I agree on the organic requirement, but I think what we disagree on is whether information in tags should be removed. If a user **doesn't** include the tag in the title, it's automatically inserted into the page title (but not the question listings on the site, so it's still helpful to include it in the tag directly). If the tag name is already in the title, the tag won't be prepended (e.g. on Google, you might see either 'javascript - How do I sort an array?' or 'How do I sort an array in JavaScript', but never 'javascript - How do I sort an array in JavaScript').

Comment: Zanon You don't want to see "[JavaScript] JavaScript: In JavaScript how to select element using JavaScript in browser with JavaScript [JavaScript]" - that is strange. You should express passion for JavaScript everywhere :)

Comment: There one somewhat positive side of all those minor edits - they fill out review queue quickly and discourage reviewers from actually reviewing the changes... So no more bad/minor edits can be made... (not exactly serious, but looking at edits that fix spelling in greetings and thank you notes make me wish edit queue is blocked all the time)

Comment: Why does it matter how much reputation the user has?

Comment: @MathieuK., when you have more than 2k rep, edits have immediate effect. They don't need to me reviewed by others. See this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit).

Answer (score 6):

I would consider (clearly) incorrect capitalisation of names of things to be a spelling mistake and as such that fixing that in the title to be an acceptable edit.

Also, "wodpress" is misspelled (missing an "r"), making an even better argument for a standalone edit.

**HOWEVER:**

"WordPress" doesn't belong in those titles in the first place, as [the other answer pointed out](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), and the second title is just bad.

So the correct response would be "Reject and Edit" to remove "wodpress" from the title altogether (and fix the second title).

Comment: Saying it's an acceptable edit in your first sentence makes "**Approve and Edit**" a better choice than _Reject and edit_.

Comment: @Cœur But "'WordPress' doesn't belong in those titles in the first place", which I why I can't recommend approving it, because the editor is fixing something that should be removed, which is behaviour that should be corrected, not encouraged.

Comment: Fair. After all I do _reject and edit_ for spelling corrections on "thx 4 ur help".