# My question was downvoted because I didn't capitalize

Tags: discussion, downvotes

My question was downvoted and edited because I didn't capitalize. I didn't capitalize the first word of the title.

Is that really useful editing?

Comment: Sure, that's *a* reason for someone to downvote, but I don't think that's *the* reason...

Comment: It's a good reason to edit, though. It improves readability.

Comment: Nothing to worry about, somebody else surely will downvote it for the correct reason.

Comment: That edit was bad, primarily because it was incomplete. But the capitalization is not the main problem of the question.

Comment: @makoto, leaving aside the quality of the question (how can I ask a community for sample code?) Is it really useful to downvote a question because the first word isn't capitalised. How does that improve the quality of questions?

Comment: Now you're assuming that was the reason for the downvotes. You can't ignore question quality here.

Comment: @GrahamNicholls You can't directly. You can ask about a specific programming problem which you're trying to solve, the answers will likely include code that achieves what you want. Change it to say you want to list all the sockets in WAIT_TIMEOUT and show your attempts so far to use the plugin to do that for example. The question is probably reopenable through editing.

Comment: I fail to see the problem with asking for sample code to use a plugin, btw. The code could count elephant knees - it's irrelevant.  I also see little evidence on google, of anyone using the plugin, which makes me suspicious that it is useful. Again , please tell me why it's too broad. Should I ask for knee counting code?

Comment: @Bart I'm surprised it's even possible to make a suggested edit that small. Surely just capitalizing the title isn't within the 6 character threshold.

Comment: *So I'll work it out and answer my own question. Pretty sure someone will find the answer useful, which is surely a criterion of value, no?* - You can't answer a question that's On Hold or Closed, you have to get it re-opened first.

Comment: i dV imPropERly formAtted quEstioNS 2 BecAusE i H8 lokG @ th3m.... But I doubt that was the reason in your case.

Comment: @BSMP isn't there something separate for title-only edits (my memory fails me here)

Comment: @Bart - [You're right.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/346358/capitalization-edits-of-popular-terms-in-question-title-as-the-only-edit) I don't know how I missed that Meta post.

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs  Really? You're comparing not using a capital in what's not a sentence anyway with what you wrote.   Thanks for such a positive and useful contribution .

Answer (score 23):

I can probably state without fear of contradiction that the missing capital *wasn't* the reason for the down-vote.

The question is too broad and a request for an off site resource and should be closed.

Comment: where am I requesting an off-site resource?

Comment: @GrahamNicholls - "Does anyone have any example code," OK, you were probably asking for the code to be posted as an answer, so maybe I wasn't 100% accurate there, but the question is definitely too broad.

Comment: So how do I ask if anyone has done this before? There's nothing in google. Are you saying that SO is the wrong place. IMO it's a useful question for someone following.

Comment: I am not asking how to find time wait sockets. I am trying to find sample code for the collectd lua plugin.

Comment: You don't ask if someone has done it before. You state your problem, show your attempts at a solution, and clearly state where it falls short. Tutorials and sharing of general code in a response to broad questions is not what the site is about.

Comment: @GrahamNicholls But if someone showed you how to write code to find time wait sockets using the plugin for example, you could probably figure out how to do other things using the plugin yourself.

Comment: The collectd lua plugin is a very specific problem, not generic code. I have written 000s of loc in lua. The docs for the plugin aren't complete. A solution is probably 20 loc.

Comment: So I'll work it out and answer my own question. Pretty sure someone will find the answer useful, which is surely a criterion of value, no?

Comment: @RobertLongson So what?  This isn't me cheating on my homework.  A concrete example would be useful for anyone using the plugin.

Comment: @GrahamNicholls sure, it's just a matter of how you pose the question. It just needs to be more specific than "a concrete example".

Comment: Take a look at this question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1022560/subtle-differences-between-javascript-and-lua?rq=1   It has a lower case first letter, and seems IMO to be both overly broad, and (arguably) opinion-based, yet it has a lot of upvotes, including one for what I consider a silly turn of phrase (I hate colloquialisms - they exclude).

Comment: ~9 year old questions aren’t a useful comparison, things have evolved immeasurably since then. Always post to current standards/guidelines, that’s what questions are judged on

Comment: Well it was the first question which appeared in the sidebar when I was looking.  You're saying that it was a useful question, but no longer is.   Seems somewhat arbitrary.  But now I'm in danger of taking this far too seriously.